# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'StringVar' and 'str'

Tags: python, tkinter, messagebox

it givs me this error (unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'StringVar' and 'str')

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()
root.geometry ('640x600') # Size of the window 
root.resizable(0, 0) # makes the window adjustable with its features
def convert():
    gtr =float(a.get())
    c = gtr + gtr + gtr + gtr
    c= StringVar()
    msg = messagebox.showinfo("Completed!!", c + "USD")

Label(root, text = "Welcome to Convertor From EGP to USD", fg="black").pack()
a = Entry(root)
a.insert(0, "Amount of Money")
a.pack()
submit = Button(root, tex
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, if you're adding something to a string using the `+` sign, the other thing must also be a string.

But in your case you're trying to add a `StringVar` object, which is not a string.

You can use the `.get()` method to access the *contents* of the `StringVar` object:

```
c.get() + "USD"
```

I imagine this would also work:

```
str(c) + "USD"
```

Comment: `str(c)` will get the name of the variable, not the content of the variable.

Comment: @acw1668 I'm pretty sure that's wrong...

Answer (score 0):

- Comment out on line 10, `#c= StringVar()`
- Used f-format string on line 12,
  `messagebox.showinfo(f"Completed!!,{c}USD")`

Code:

```
def convert():
    gtr =float(a.get())
    c = gtr + gtr + gtr + gtr
    #c= StringVar()
    messagebox.showinfo(f"Completed!!", f"{c} USD")
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Note that the first argument and second argument of `messagebox.showinfo()` are the title and message.  Your solution combines the two into one, so it will be shown as title and the message will be empty.